# Sed regex command replacement

Tags: regex, bash, sed

In my php.ini I have

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

I want to change it back to

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
```

with the sed command

```
sed -i "s/^error_reporting = .*/error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT/" /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

I get a different result:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL error_reporting = E_ALL ~E_DEPRECATED error_reporting = E_ALL ~E_STRICT
```

but it should be

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
```

BTW, the sed command is in a bash script.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`&` has a special meaning in the replacement clause of a sed `s` command; it is replaced by the matched string. You have to escape it:

```
sed -i 's/^error_reporting = .*/error_reporting = E_ALL \& ~E_DEPRECATED \& ~E_STRICT/' /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```